# Reattach moved files from another branch in git

Tags: git

Let's say I have two branches for my project: stable and master.
In the master branch, some time ago, I have manually moved some files, unfortunately not with the `git mv` command, but by hand, thus it seemed git didn't mark this move (although it usually does).

Now I have the problem that every time I do some changes on the stable branch on those files, and I want to merge these changes back to master, it always tell me that these changes are whole new files, it doesn't just display the changes, making it very difficult to merge, not only because I have to merge these files my hand now, but also since these files tend to divert, things are getting weirder day after day.

Is it possible to inform git now that these two files are actually the same and display differences only, as it would do if I had performed `git mv` in the first place?

Comment: From what I recall, it doesn't really matter if you use `git mv` or just `mv` with regard to moving files.  In general, it is difficult to track diffs across moving/renamed files in Git (you can search SO for more information on this).  My advice would be to just not move/rename files if you plan to have two different versions of things in two different branches long term.

Comment: I know that in general it doesn't matter, but I am sure it usually keeps track of things and on other files indeed has marked a mv instead .

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is correct, git does not record moves, it uses something called a similarity index to determine if two files are the same. If it isn't detecting the files as moved, you have A) modified more than 50% of the file or B) have an actual merge conflict between changes made in the two branches

Comment: The moved files on the master branch are new files because they have different paths now. `git log --diff-filter=R --name-status master` to find out which files are renamed.

Comment: @LightBender Since the files don't have changes  more than 50% (only changes a couple of lines of code) you propose that this is a genuine merge conflict?

Comment: It's possible. Does it hault the merge? or does it just drop the files in? The former suggests conflict and the latter it not detecting the move due to the similarity index. From what you're describing, I'm inclined to think the latter. You can fiddle with the similarity index when you diff the branches to see if that is the case. `git diff -M50 stable master` adjusting the similarity index down until you detect it as a move. You can also diff the current branchs and the merge base to determine if you've changed more than half the file use `git merge-base stable master` to find the base.

Comment: These commands were really useful, please post them as an answer to accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [LightBender commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299395/reattach-moved-files-from-another-branch-in-git#comment79562387_46299395), Git does *rename detection* rather than *rename tracking*.  In Git 2.9 or newer, this detection is turned on by default for plain `git diff` as well, but if your Git is earlier or you need to lower the rename-detection threshold, you can specify the `-M` option, plus a "similarity index" number.

You can also specify a particular similarity index to use when merging, using `-X find-renames=<number>` (the number has the same form in both commands, and the same default of `50` meaning "50% similar").

Note that you really should be comparing the *merge base* of the two branch tips to *each tip*, to see what gets detected as a rename. Only if one tip is sufficiently similar to the merge base does comparing the two tips suffice. As a simplified example, suppose some base file reads, in its entirety:

```
alfa_
bravo
charl
delta
echo_
```

(I've made 5 lines all the same length so that percentages work out nicely).

In branch X, this same file reads:

```
foxtr
golf_
charl
delta
echo_
```

In branch Y, the file reads:

```
alfa_
bravo
charl
hotel
india
```

and in one of the two branches, the file is also renamed (from "pilot alphabet" to ["NATO phonetic alphabet"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet), perhaps):

```
...--B--o--...--L   <-- branch_X
      \
       o--...--R   <-- branch_Y
```

Here, commit `B` is the merge base, with the original file with its original name.  Compare it to commit `L` in branch X, and it's 60% the same: two out of five lines changed.  Compare it to commit `R` in branch Y, and it's 60% the same: a different two out of five lines changed.  So Git can match up the three files, even though one of the three has a different name.

Compare commit `L` to commit `R`, however, and the file is only 20% similar: only the `charl` (charlie-for-C) line matches!